# Add values ​from another array, python

Tags: python

I have two sql queries, which I store in two arrays each; my first array contains 9 positions and the second 16, but I want to bring only certain positions from the second to the first.

What I can think of is to go through the first array (CutPoint) and look for the value of position [0] in the second array (Validations) and call the positions that I want.

This is my code, what I have tried.

```
def Base_adherencia():
    apro = PuntoDeCorte()
    val = Validaciones()

    base = []

## create array base    
    for row in apro:
        base.append(row)
        
    for row in val:
        a = base[0]
        b = val [0]
        if a == b:
            base.append(val[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17])

    for row in base:
        print(row)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbScN.png)

Comment: Please explain in more detail (input, expected output, actual output) what problem you're having with the current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two lists together like so

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

It looks like you are trying to add everything after the first value of `val` to `apro`. You don't need the `for` loops, just take a slice of `val` and add it to `apro` if the first values match

```
if val[0] == apro[0]:
    base = val + apro[1:]
```